# Auto toggle field

Tags: javascript, html, xml

at this moment i have a field on my page that can be toggled on or off with a button.
But i would like to have the field be automatically visible depending on what's in the field.
in other words, the field UserId get's the current user's id from the Xml.
If the user id would be for example M.Bros or L. Bros, then the field should be visible, but it should be invisible for anybody else.

```
    <div id="content" style="display:block;">
        <table datasrc="#XmlUserInfo">
            <tr>
            <td style="height: 28px">UserID</td>
            <td style="height: 28px">
            <input datafld="UID" name="UserId" size="35" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleContent() {
    //Get the DOM reference
    var contentId = document.getElementById("content");
    //Toggle
    contentId.style.display == "block" ? contentId.style.display = "none" :
    contentId.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<button onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `document.getElementByName('UserId').onchange ...`?

Comment: Works as [expected](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hjcx/). What else?

Comment: we need your code when you're filling the UserId field...

Comment: at the moment i am using the button to toggle between the on or off state, but i would like to do this automatically depending on who is looking at the page. This is more than probable something extremely simple for somebody who is experienced in this area, but i do not have enough experience yet to reach this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the textbox to be visible when it has text in it then try getting the ID of the textbox, in your case UID..

if( UID.value == '' )UID.style.display = 'none' else UID.style.display = 'block';